# HTML max-width does't work on cell

Tags: html, width, cell

I am about to create a simple HTML table. I'd like some of the cells to dont change their width, not even if the available space for the table increases (eg: higher resolution).

I have created a [JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/5NDH4/7/) with my code. My problem is that if I move the vertical separator all the way to the left the column with the delete button starts to get wider instead of keeping its size.

Please help me out how can I do it.
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <title>User Management</title>

    <body>
        <table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width:80%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="/link1" method="post">
                        <div style="max-width:60px;display:block;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
                            <input type="button" name="Confirm" value="Delete" onclick="UserConfirm(this)" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <form action="/link2/" method="post">
                    <td style="margin:10px;max-width:60px;">
                        <input type="text" name="id" value="1" style="display:none" />1</td>
                    <td style="margin:10px;">
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="1" style="display:none" />johnd</td>
                    <td style="margin:10px;">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John" style="width: 80px;" maxlength="10" required />
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign some small width for the TD of your button like below.

```
 <td width="10">
                <form action="/link1" method="post">
                    <div style="max-width:60px;display:block;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
                        <input type="button" name="Confirm" value="Delete" onclick="UserConfirm(this)" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/5NDH4/8/)